# Why does gradle not find the resources?

Tags: gradle, npm, build.gradle

I'm currently trying to migrate a project from Gradle 3.5 to the latest Gradle version 4.9. and I'm running into the problem, that Gradle doesn't find the resources that it needs to execute the junit tests. These resources are generated upfront and contain some configuration files and referential data.

The project uses a combination of npm and Gradle to compile. Usually we run a npm script which executes a couple of tasks sequentially using `run-s`, e.g. webpack builds to generate some static resources. At the end we compile everything together using Gradle. The last Gradle task also executes the junit tests. This step fails and makes the whole build fail. The Gradle runner complains that some resources are not found, although the get properly copied to the right places.

When I execute `./gradlew test --rerun-tasks` (Yes, we use the wrapper, which has been properly upgraded, too) right after the last Gradle build step failed, it executed the junit tests successfully.

I know, that the directory structure changed in Gradle 4.x, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

My suspicion is, that it has something to do with how we normally run the whole build process. Something in the combination with `npm`.

Comment: You're basically asking us why an unknown build script causes an unknown task to throw an unknown error. We can't possibly answer such a question.

Comment: I will ask this question again with more information.